# Adding fictitious levels to a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I am trying to use the confusionMatrix() function in the caret package.
However, that requires the test dataset and the predictions derived from the training dataset
to have exactly the same levels. Because of data issues, it may happen that I need to add fictitious
levels with 0 occurrences to the test dataset. Is there any way to do this?

The reproducible toy example follows:

```
test <- data.frame (Feature=c("1200","1000","1000"), Class = c("a","b","b"))
predicted_model <- c("a","a","b","c")
```

Obviously,

```
confusionMatrix(predicted_model,test$Class)
```

yields the error message,

```
 Error in confusionMatrix.default(predicted_model, test$Class) : 
  the data cannot have more levels than the reference
```

The objective is to add a fictitious Class c to test, such that by running

```
 table(test$Class)
```

we get:

```
a b c
1 2 0
```

How would you do it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
test <- data.frame (Feature=c("1200","1000","1000"), Class = c("a","b","b"))
test$Class <- factor(test$Class, levels = c("a", "b", "c"))
test
#   Feature Class
# 1    1200     a
# 2    1000     b
# 3    1000     b  


table(test$Class)
# a b c 
# 1 2 0
```

Comment: Thanks! Simpler than I thought, kinda forgot how to increase artificially the levels...

Comment: You're welcome! Don't you love it when that happens? Just be careful not to relevel by doing `levels(<some factor>) <- c(<some levels>)`. It looks like it does what you want, but it doesn't.